# Gentoo, Fuerte and PCL

Tags: ros, pcl, gentoo, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"rosdep install" doesn't seem to find the dependency for PCL. I have looked in the gentoo.yaml file and it has "package: pcl" but gentoo has no package. There is an overlay commented out above it but I don't know how it suppose to work as is.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55136/gentoo,-fuerte-and-pcl/) by [MUNCS](https://answers.ros.org/users/3923/muncs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-02-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the [installation instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Gentoo) and make sure you have setup your sources correctly.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0